# proper way to debug sql result in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using

```
    puts @object.inspect
```

to debug the results of queries in rails, but the output doesn't seem to include any joins I've defined for the query. How do I get the full array to show?

For example, if I do the following

```
    @object = Object.joins("JOIN associations ON associations.id = object.association_id")
      .where(:id => params[:object_id])
      .select("objects.*, associations.*")
      .first
    puts @object.inspect
```

I get the all the Object fields in my debug array, but none of the association fields. Yet they are there when I try to use them in my view (@object.association_field etc)

PS - the above query looks ugly, I'm only trying to pull one record, but I was getting various errors if I tried to use .find() instead of .where().first. Suggestions welcome on how to make it more railsy

Comment: you might find this helpful http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

Why not the simplest possible way:

```
@object = Object.find(params[:object_id])
@association = @object.associations.first
puts "#{@object.inspect}, #{@association.inspect}"
```

(assuming that `has_many :associations` is defined in Object)

And the reason you are not getting fields for association is because the only thing that `joins` does is joining to another table in SQL. It does not fetch joined data. `select` only select subset of object's attributes, I think the rest is just ignored.